# Access toolbar object from SlidingTabLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-tablayout

How can I access the toolbar object created in mainActivity from the SlidingTabLayout.Java class?

What I am trying to do is to change the color of the toolbar depending on the tab currently selected.

I am trying to do this from within the actionListener of SlidingTabLayout but here I can't access the toolbar (findviewbyid returns nullpointer).

Thanks

Comment: Please add supporting code

Answer (score 0):

create a method getToolbar which returns `Toolbar` and then call it from your `SlidingTabLayout` class.

Here's a snippet

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;

    public Toolbar getToolbar() {
        return toolbar;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    }
}
```